# Understanding the function in c program . char * allocc(){} K&R page 101

Tags: c

I trying to understand the following function.

Can I get the correct working?

```
#define ALLOCSIZE 1000

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static char *allocp = allocbuf;
char *alloc(int n)
{ 
    if(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n)
    {
       allocp += n;
       return allocp - n;
    }
    else
      return 0;
}
```

---

Reference : http://www.learntosolveit.com/cprogramming/alloc_afree.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This `alloc` implementation

It implements a `malloc`-like function based on a static buffer (but doesn't allow to `free` the allocated buffer since the handed out buffer is not tracked). That is you call `alloc` with the number of bytes you want to use, and get either an pointer to the buffer or 0 if the buffer isn't available. Let's break it up.

```
static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static char *allocp = allocbuf;
```

`allocbuf` is the actual buffer that's going to hold the data. To work with it we're using a pointer `allocp`, which now points to the start of the buffer.

```
char *alloc(int n)
{ 
    if(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n)
```

When requesting a buffer we check if the buffer parts already used leaves enough space to satisfy the request. For this pointer arithmetics is used: we calculate the end of the buffer (by adding `allocbuf` and `ALLOCSIZE`), then substract the start of the unused buffer (`allocp`). This yields the number of bytes left in the buffer, and then we can simply check if the requested bytes is less.

```
    {
       allocp += n;
       return allocp - n;
    }
    else
      return 0;
}
```

If we have enough buffer available we increment `allocp`. It now points to the first byte after the buffer part we just allocated. Then we return a pointer to the beginning of the buffer part we just allocated, so the caller can use it. To the caller it's similar to `malloc`: you request a buffer and either get a pointer to it or `NULL`. If you get a valid pointer you can then use it.

This allows the caller to call `alloc` multiple times and each time get a new chunk of the buffer pointed to, as long as there is space available.

## Use of dynamic memory

Simply put, dynamic memory is used when you need to handle data but don't know about the size at compile time.

For example, if you're reading data from a file you can use a static buffer with a size you specify during compile time, but then you cannot read files larger than that (or need to add special handling to read the file in chunks, but that might not work depending on your application).

Now if you dynamically allocate the memory you're not limited to the size you set during compilation. You can then read files of any size (only limited by the memory available on your computer.)

## `malloc` vs. (this) `alloc`

There's a couple of differences, I'll focus on the important ones here.

First, there are different locations where data is placed. Variables are placed on the *stack*, global data is placed in a section called *bss* or *data* (depending if the data is initialized. Also, those sections can be named slightly differently depending on your system and compiler). Dynamic memory uses a section called *heap*.

This `alloc` implementation uses a statically allocated buffer, so the data is placed in the bss section. `malloc` instead uses the heap.

Second, this implementation is way more limited than `malloc` is. Along with `malloc` comes `free` which can release a buffer again. Also, since `alloc` uses a static buffer size it's limited by that size -- `malloc` is limited by the computer (available memory, the way the operating system handles memory etc.)

You'll use an implementation like `alloc` on limited systems: if you don't have a heap, if you don't need to free the buffer again. These are usually constraints you have on microcontrollers. On PCs you should avoid using your own implementation and simply use `malloc`.

Comment: may i get any example .or its application ?

Answer (score 1):

This function implements a simple memory allocation interface, similar to `malloc`.  Memory is allocated out of a fixed-size array called `allocbuf`.  The pointer `allocp` points to the next free byte in the array.  When called, it checks to see if there's enough room to satisfy the request.  The amount of allocated memory is `allocp - allocbuf`.  Subtracting this from the total amount of memory, `ALLOCSIZE`, gives the amount remaining.  So `ALLOCSIZE - (allocp - allocbuf)` which is just `ALLOCSIZE - allocp + allocbuf`, or `allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp`.  To me that's the most intuitive way to view it, but you can also think of it as the end of the buffer minus the first free address in the buffer.

In any case, if there's enough room, it adjusts `allocp` by adding `n`, then returns the original value of `allocp` as the address of the newly allocated memory.  Otherwise it returns 0.